# python MANIFEST.ini proper recursive-include syntax

Tags: python, pip

In my MANIFEST.py I have:

```
recursive-include **/static *
```

This gets called via my requirement.txt by having just a '.' on the last line.

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the following error from glob.py:
   TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

I have worked around this issue by changing the manifest file to:

```
recursive-include ./**/static *
```

But this is causing problems in my docker image, is there a correct way to specify this search from the root ?